# Apple Framework ISA Classicifications

Tags: ios, macos, frameworks

I was wondering, how do frameworks store multiple architecture (ISA) types? Do they?

It was my understanding that an Apple framework was just a special folder structure with a sim-link to the most-recent library to be used. However, I have noticed that an Xcode project which may build for multiple different ISA types, only has one instance of a given framework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I have found an answer to this question myself. Typically, frameworks are developed with `lipo`: https://ss64.com/osx/lipo.html. A simple `lipo -info` on the framework's sim-linked fat file show that it contains multiple arch types.